# Regex Fetch part of string as number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-selectors

I've a string something like

```
<dt>Source:</dt>
<dd>
    Emergence: Title; 2005, Vol. 9 Issue 30, p120-203, 12p
</dd>
```

Now I am a regex to fetch different values for it, i.e. : Volume, issue, date etc
so, I fetch entire text using :

```
var attr = jQuery("dl dt:contains('Source:') ~ dd:eq(0)").text();
```

And use regex to fetch different values, such as :

To fetch start page I use, following regex:

```
var regex = new RegExp("p\\d+(?=[-\\s]{1})");

var regexValPS = attr.match(regex);
```

Return value : p120, expected : 120

Similarly, to fetch Volume info, I use following, regex:

```
var regexVol = new RegExp("Vol.\\s\\d+");
var regexValVol = attributeVal.match(regexVol);
```

I get : **Vol. 9** , I want : **9**

Similarly I am getting issue number with  "Issue" text :

```
var regEx = new RegExp("Issue\\s\\d+");
var regExVal = attributeVal.match(regEx);
```

I Should get : **30** instead : **Issue 30**

The problem is I can't use another regex to get the desired value, can't strip/parseInt etc, and the pattern must be able to fetch information in a single regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grouping `(...)` and read its match »

#### Demo:

```
var str = "Emergence: Title; 2005, Vol. 9 Issue 30, p120-203, 12p";
var re = /p(\d+)(?=[\-\s])/;
document.writeln(re.exec(str)[1]); // prints: 120
re = /Vol\.\s(\d+)/;
document.writeln(re.exec(str)[1]); // prints: 9
```

Test it [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/HBpEg/).

Answer (score 1):

Toget the desired info using a single regex, you need to take advantage of regex grouping:

```
var regEx = new RegExp("Issue\\s(\\d+)");
var regExVal = attributeVal.match(regEx)[1];
```

If you cannot modify the regex, you can maybe parse the resulting number :

```
var number = "Issue 30".replace(/\D/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you do not want to do further parsing on the string values returned by the `.match()` calls, but can accept a different regular expression if it returns the necessary values in one statement.

Your regex needs a capture group `()` to retrieve the desired numbers, and place them in an array index `[]` (the first index `[0]` will hold the entire matched string, and subsequent indices hold the `()` captured substrings).

Instead of `new RegExp()` you can use the simpler `/pattern/` regex literal in this case, and it is possible to extract the desired value in a single statement for all cases.

```
var yourString = '<dt>Source:</dt>\
<dd>\
    Emergence: Title; 2005, Vol. 9 Issue 30, p120-203, 12p\
</dd>';

// Match the page, captured in index [1]
yourString.match(/p(\d+)(?=[-\s]{1})/)[1];
// "120"

// Match the Vol captured in index [1]
yourString.match(/Vol\.\s(\d+)/)[1];
// "9"

// Match the issue captured in index [1]
yourString.match(/Issue\s(\d+)/)[1];
// "30"
```

[**Here it is on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TTM7g/)

Comment: thanx, you understood me correctly, all I wanted was to be able to parse the values in single Regex. Well, I can't directly use Group capture, but, let me see how I can make use of it...
Thnx every1 for resoponses

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var attr = jQuery("dt:contains('Source:') ~ dd:eq(0)").text();
console.log(attr);
console.log(attr.match(/p(\d+)(?=[-\s]{1})/)[1]);
console.log(attr.match(/Vol\.\s(\d+)/)[1]);
console.log(attr.match(/Issue\s(\d+)/)[1]);
```

For more details: [JQUERY REGEX EXAMPLES TO USE WITH .MATCH()](http://www.jquery4u.com/syntax/jquery-basic-regex-selector-examples/).